# butterknife edit text and "cannot resolve symbol" string

Tags: android, butterknife

I'm having some issues with using `Butterknife` and getting text from `EditTexts`. I have an activity with many `EditTexts`. For brevity sake, I'll only include 2-3 in my code example(s). I'm eventually taking the entered text and using it with iText's library to spit out a PDF.

First, I'm binding views with Butterknife:

```
public class NewPatientActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


@BindView(R.id.new_patient_editText_last_name)
TextInputEditText lastNameTextInputEditText;

@BindView(R.id.new_patient_editText_nick_name)
TextInputEditText nickNameTextInputEditText;

@BindView(R.id.new_patient_editText_date_of_birth)
TextInputEditText dateOfBirthTextInputEditText;
```

Then I `ButterKnife.bind(this);` in `onCreate()`.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_patient);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}
```

Then, clicking on my floating action button is supposed to grab the text that was entered text in the `EditTexts`:

```
@OnClick(R.id.floating_action_button)
public void finishedPatientNotesFabClick(View view) {

    try {


        String lastNameText = lastNameTextInputEditText.getText().toString();

        String nickNameText = nickNameTextInputEditText.getText().toString();

        String dateOfBirth = dateOfBirthTextInputEditText.getText().toString();

    }
```

Then I try using those strings when I use them as the parameter for constructing a new Paragraph:

```
 private static void addBioAndContactInfoChapter(Document document) throws DocumentException {


    bioAndContactInfoChapter.add(new Paragraph(R.string.patient_last_name) + ": " +
            lastNameText);

    bioAndContactInfoChapter.add(new Paragraph(R.string.patient_nickname) + ": " +
            nickNameText);

    bioAndContactInfoChapter.add(new Paragraph(R.string.patient_date_of_birth) + ": " +
            dateOfBirth);
```

But here's where the problem is. When I use those strings, I get the

> cannot resolve symbol '__string name'.

The Paragraph class has a constructor which only takes a String, so I don't think that's the issue. Is something funky happening because of Butterknife or what? Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

[image]

Answer (score 3):

From the sniplets, your `String lastNameText`, `nickNameText` and `dateOfBirth` seem to be local to your method `finishedPatientNotesFabClick`. Most probably that's why they are not accessible inside `addBioAndContactInfoChapter` method. Declare those variables outside the method and assign the values to them inside the `OnClickListener`.

Comment: Still not working. I declared "private String lastNameText;" right after the initial Butterknife bind before onCreate(). Then in the onClickListener, I did "            lastNameText = lastNameTextInputEditText.getText().toString();"  but when I try to use the "lastNameText" string, [now I get "non-static field cannot be referenced from a static context"](http://imgur.com/a/kQiGD)

Comment: Right. Your method is static. So your variable needs to be static as well, if you want to access it inside that method. Declare the variable as static. Or if you don't need the method to be static, remove that from the method. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/413898/what-does-the-static-keyword-do-in-a-class might help in understanding more about static keyword.